# R: How to pack the seasonal components of time-series to an array-like structure?

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to calculate the decomposition of 34 time-series to study the similarity of seasonal components, as explains this [this tutorial](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/timeseries.html)

I start from a CSV that, after some transformations and slicing it is converted in a data.frame of 34 rows (timeseries) and 108 columns (vegetation value in a particular date). Using the following function I developed, I obtain the decomposition of the time series:

```
None of the following initializations work

signals_ndvi_seasonal = data.frame()
signals_ndvi_seasonal = vector()
    decompose_signal <- function(ts, site, i){
      a_signal_ndvi = data.frame(ts)
      ts_ndvi = ts(a_signal_ndvi, frequency=12, start=c(2006,1))
      # Apparently, if we dont do this second step, the type of 
      # ts_ndvi is "mts" instead of "ts". To be able to decompose
      # the signal, we need a type "ts". Why? To me it makes no sense.
      ts_ndvi2 = ts(ts_ndvi[1,], frequency=12, start=c(2006,1))
      dec_ndvi = decompose(ts_ndvi2)
    signals_ndvi_seasonal[i] = dec_ndvi$season
      plot(dec_ndvi)
    }
```

Now, I want to access `dec_ndvi$season`, that contains the time series of my seasonal component **and append it to some kind of array/vector/list/whatever** so I can further use the package `dtw` to study the similarity of the components. Like this:

```
distMatrix <- dtwDist(signals_ndvi, method="DTW")
```

And finally to a nice plot:

```
corrplot(distMatrix, is.corr = FALSE, method = "circle")
```

The **sad thing here** is that I succeeded in calculating the similarity with all the components of the signal but I am too new to R (usually I do Python) that the R syntax and data types are quite unclear to me. **So I am very stuck with the data types**, I guess. I am getting empty data frames back, concatenations and binds that do not concatenate, vectors that contain null values and other different things, except whatever that ressembles an array of time series.

Therefore, I need a way of packing my time-series so I can pass them to `dtwDist` as I did with the non-decomposed time series in variable `signals_ndvi`. Thanks!

Comment: seems there is a lot of complain and you see things much more difficult as they actually are.... Question yourself: what's the input, what's the output? I guess the input is the dataframe containing 34 time series , each with 108 observations and the column names are the dates of observations.
Starting from there, it would be better: either to work on columns so a column would be a timeseries, either to have a list of zoo timeseries. What do you want as output (for me this point is not clear)?

Comment: 1) The input to decompose is a type ts (time series). 2) The output of decompose is decompose.ts type. 3) If I print the seasonal component like print(dec_ndvi$seasonal), I see the values. 4) How to append this dec_ndvi$seasonal to an array so I can reuse this calculation in further processing? Perhaps I even dare to create another time-series with the dec_ndvi$seasonal to study the similarity of seasonal components. The thing is not as simple as getting + plotting a graphical output, I need to reuse the calculations and I have problems with the data types/structures. That's it......